# Matrix over the field

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Suppose we are given a matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\ 1&0&1\\ 1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ over the field  $P=\left\{1,0\right\}$. What kind of matrix $A$ as an multiplicative semigroup element and what order does it have?

Comment: I don't know exactly what "What kind of matrix $A$ as an multiplicative semigroup element" means, but have you tried calculating, say, $A^2$ and $A^3$, and seen what happens?

Answer (score 1):

A calculation shows that $A^4=A$, so that the powers of $A$ are just $A.A^2$ and $A^3$. But since $A$ is not invertible over $\mathbb{F}_2$, we cannot conclude that $A^3=I$. In fact, there is no $n\ge 1$ such that $A^n=I$.